# Is there any way to download csv file from “website button click” using Python?

Tags: javascript, python, url

I want to automate the download of a CSV file `"Projects.csv"` from this website:

> https://www.vcsprojectdatabase.org/#/projects/st_/c_/ss_0/so_/di_/np_

The CSV can be downloaded manually by clicking the CSV icon but I'm not sure how can I automate this download in python and store the CSV file locally on my drive.

So far I have tried inspecting the button element via chrome developer console to find the correct url in the Network tab like so?

> https://www.vcsprojectdatabase.org/services/publicViewServices/fetchProjectsExport

But I'm not sure if this URL should include the name of file at the end like this:

> https://www.vcsprojectdatabase.org/services/publicViewServices/fetchProjectsExport/Projects.csv

This is what I have tried but it just writes a blank file:

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.vcsprojectdatabase.org/services/publicViewServices/fetchProjectsExport/Projects.csv'

r = requests.get(url)
with open('a.csv', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(r.content)
```

How do I get the CSV file to properly download and save?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First of all, you should understand that HTTP protocol based on [**requests**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods). Final result of JavaScript execution will be formed HTTP request which let server respond with file content. You need to "reverse" web page, find how to create proper request and repeat it as similar as it can be done.

So, let's try to do this step by step:

1. Click right mouse button on element which execute download and press "Inspect element"
   [image]
2. In source code you can see name of JavaScript function this element executes
   [image]
3. Type the name of function in console without parentheses and click button which should appear near console return (This button will open this JavaScript function in source code)
   [image]
4. In source code we see that function execute submit on HTML element which has id `frmDownload`. So, go back to "Inspector" tab and type this id into search box.
   [image]
5. Now we found that this element is HTML [form](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp). This form send [POST](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST) request to URL `https://www.vcsprojectdatabase.org/services/publicViewServices/fetchProjectsExport` with next data:

   ```
   searchTerm=
   country=
   sectoral_scope=0
   recentProjects=
   sort=projectId
   dir=DESC
   formatType=csv
   ```

   This information is enough to try repeat this request in Python.

Let's write small script which form and send same request and save result into .csv file:

```
import requests

data = {
    "searchTerm": "",
    "country": "",
    "sectoral_scope": "0",
    "recentProjects": "",
    "sort": "projectId",
    "dir": "DESC",
    "formatType": "csv"
}

file = requests.post("https://www.vcsprojectdatabase.org/services/publicViewServices/fetchProjectsExport", data)

with open("res.csv", "wb+") as f:
    f.write(file.content)
```

Launch it and it ... works. `res.csv` contains proper result.

**BUT THAT'S NOT ALL.** Usually everything is not so easy. To let our request look same as sent by browser we should take a look on [request headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers). To capture HTTP request from browser we can open "Network" tab:

[image]

Now let's press download button on web page and download csv file. In requests table now we can see our post request. Click on it and take a look on "Headers" tab into "Request headers" section.

[image]

There's [Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) header, which mostly in such as requests is not important and can be missed. But if you have some issues with request you should take a look on previous requests, find request with `Set-Cookie` header in server response and repeat it.

Let's improve our script and copy important *(Host, Content-Length, Connection we don't include, cause Python requests module will add them automatically; DNT and Upgrade-Insecure-Requests are not necessary at all)* headers from browser.

```
import requests

data = {
    "searchTerm": "",
    "country": "",
    "sectoral_scope": "0",
    "recentProjects": "",
    "sort": "projectId",
    "dir": "DESC",
    "formatType": "csv"
}

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0",
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
    "Accept-Language":  "en-US,en;q=0.5",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "Referer": "https://www.vcsprojectdatabase.org/",
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
}

file = requests.post("https://www.vcsprojectdatabase.org/services/publicViewServices/fetchProjectsExport", data,
                     headers=headers)

with open("res.csv", "wb+") as f:
    f.write(file.content)
```

**P.S.** Don't forget to ask website owner for permission

Comment: Thanks very much! This works perfectly and your step by step process helps me understand it better also. I now need to go and improve my JavaScript knowledge!

Comment: @OlvinRoght - Your Answer is very helpful, I'd highly appreciate it, if you could help my similar situation.

https://stackoverflow.com/q/66298758/10939394

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining it in detail / step by step!

Answer (score -1):

The request type is POST and you need to specify the appropriate headers, which you can see in the developer console. Also, you would not to provide the form data. The below code works.

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.vcsprojectdatabase.org/services/publicViewServices/fetchProjectsExport?searchTerm=&country=&sectoral_scope=0&recentProjects=&sort=projectId&dir=DESC&formatType=csv'
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded','Accept': 'text/csv'}

r = requests.post(url,headers=headers)
with open('a.csv', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(r.content)
```

Comment: It's **very bad practice** to send data in POST request as GET request params. Yes, it works in this request but you'll definitely get problems with it soon.