# Downloading Books from website with python

Tags: python, file, pdf, download, python-requests

I'm downloading books from the website, and almost my code runs smoothly, but when I try to open the pdf Book on my PC. An error generated by Adobe Acrobat Reader that this is **not supported file type**.

[image: Error Image]

Here is the image of the Book formate, and I'm sure my code needs to be a correction because the formate of the book on the website is different from normally PDF Files.

[image: Book Formate Image]

Code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://global.oup.com/education/support-learning-anywhere/key-resources-online/?region=international&utm_campaign=learninganywhere&utm_source=umbraco&utm_medium=display&utm_content=support_learning_key_resources&utm_team=int#Primary'

response = requests.get(url)
soup     = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
table_data = soup.find_all('td')

books_url_list = []
for link in table_data:
    books_url = link.find('a')['href']
    books_url_list.append(books_url+'.pdf')
    
book = books_url_list[1]
book_response = requests.get(book)

with open('books.pdf', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(book_response.content)
```

`

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55919705/10824407) answer, it could be helpful.

Comment: The book links do not provide the location of a pdf. The link is to another webpage which then displays the pdf stored on the server via webpage, so the value of `book_response` is the raw html of the page shoing the book, not the pdf content of the book.

Comment: If you inspect the website, you can see that there are no PDFs that you can scrape. They are displayed as svgz files. See an example [here](http://p.calameoassets.com/200406174918-271f79d0ce92452de86df83977cbb8e0/p3.svgz). You could try to convert them with svglib.

Comment: If you open the pdf file in notepad, you will see `access denied`

Answer (score 1):

Well, I inspected element from website, then I find no '.pdf' files. We can inspect one book page using following link: https://en.calameo.com/read/000777721d10096b9e9ca?authid=gWc48kAQQoD0&region=international

After inspecting the element, I find is not pdf. It's just an image in the page.

https://p.calameoassets.com/200406174654-2bfa9441783e162c8da42a712feda3e2/p1.svgz

https://p.calameoassets.com/200406174654-2bfa9441783e162c8da42a712feda3e2/p2.svgz

....

https://p.calameoassets.com/200406174654-2bfa9441783e162c8da42a712feda3e2/p98.svgz

And so on.

So, you can write a code to download this image.