# How to get the dynamic website content using Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, webdriverwait

I'm trying to scrape a dynamic [website](https://www.aodour.pk/brand/hemani) with selenium but not be able to get the website content with selenium.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

url = 'https://www.aodour.pk/brand/hemani'
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(30) #for loading the page properly
html_js     = driver.page_source

#driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.ESCAPE)
#I tried to skip the AD but didn't know why not it skip the AD

driver.get(url) #try to reload the page again (for skipped the Ad)
time.sleep(30)
soup         = BeautifulSoup(html_js,'html.parser')
```

I have two questions.

1. Why not I'm getting the page content?
2. Why not ESCAPE keys is working for me?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend not to use time.sleep() with selenium. Instead WebDriverWait / presence_of_element_located() can be used:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

DELAY = 30
wd = webdriver.Chrome("<PATH_TO_CHROME_DRIVER>")

wd.maximize_window()
url = 'https://www.aodour.pk/brand/hemani'
wd.get(url)

try:
    # waiting for pop-up
    landing_popup = WebDriverWait(wd, DELAY).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'landing_popup')))
    # waiting for loader to vanish
    page_loader = WebDriverWait(wd, DELAY).until_not(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'pageloader')))
    # waiting for button to be clickable
    close_button = WebDriverWait(wd, DELAY).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[./span[contains(@class, "icon-close")]]')))
    wd.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", close_button)
    print("Ad skipped")
except TimeoutException:
    print("Ad pop-up didn't appeared")
except Exception as e:
    print("Error: " + str(e))


html = wd.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

print(soup)
```

Comment: that's great for me that Now the Ad is skipped. But this actually not render the website content. I mean like not showing the details of the products. Soup return me JS file content. Thanks for your support

Comment: Which product details do you want to retrieve? soup variable will contain the HTML code with the links to the product details. You can get them by class name "product-content" and locate extract text from these elements, getting product names. Using selenium you can click this links and navigate to the pages with product descriptions.

Comment: Hi Alexandra, I want to skip the Ad from the URL('https://www.aodour.pk/subcategory/face-treatments'), and I applied your method same but didn't able to skip it. Could you elaborate it more?

Answer (score 0):

Try below approach using python - [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/) simple, straightforward, reliable, fast and less code is required when it comes to requests. I have fetched the **API URL** from website itself after inspecting the network section of google chrome browser.

What exactly below script is doing:

1. First it will create the URL for the passed slug or query parameter in your case it is product name like '**hemani**'
2. After creating the URL a GET request will be sent which will then give us the details of the product mentioned in query parameter as a **JSON** object.
3. Upon getting the data script will parse the **JSON** data using **json.loads** library.
4. At last it will iterate all over the list one by one and print the details which you will mention or mentioned in the script right now, you can change or add information in the print statements below as per your need.

   ```
   import json
   import requests
   from urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning
   requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)

   def scrap_brand_data():

   SLUG = 'hemani' # dynamic parameter change as per your need
   print('Creating URL for product ',SLUG)
   URL = 'https://nodeapi.aodour.pk/api/brand/products?slug=' + SLUG #GET API URL fetched from the website
   print('URL created going to fetch data..')

   response = requests.get(URL,verify=False) #create request and get data
   extracted_data = json.loads(response.text) #parse the JSON object using JSON loads

   for data in extracted_data['result']['products']: #iterate on each and every object and print the details
       print('-' * 100)
       print('Brand Id: ',data['brandID'])
       print('Brand Name: ',data['brandName'])
       print('Brand Slug: ',data['brandSlug'])
       print('Category Name: ',data['categoryName'])
       print('Product Id: ',data['id'])
       print('Product Name: ',data['name'])
       print('Product Rating: ',data['rating'])
       print('Product Info: ',data['slug'])
       print('Product Name: ',data['name'])
       print('Brand Id: ',data['brandID'])
       print('Variations: ',data['variations'])
       print('-' * 100)

   scrap_brand_data()
   ```

[image: Actual code image]

Comment: That's great! it's too short and very easy. But can we download books with requests?  check this on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63871807/downloading-books-from-website-with-python

Comment: What is books? Is there any product available on website related to books? Sorry didn’t get you exactly

Comment: No you can't download PDF files using requests, you have to use selenium to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The website is a dynamic website built through [ReactJS](https://reactjs.org/). So to retrieve the dynamic website content using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and close the banner element and you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Code Block:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.aodour.pk/brand/hemani')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='landing_popup']/button/span[@data-dismiss='modal']"))).click()
  print(driver.page_source)
  driver.quit()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  <html lang="en" class=""><head><meta charset="utf-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"><meta name="theme-color" content="#000000"><title>WB By Hemani Products in Pakistan</title>
  .
  <div class="logo res"><a href="/track-order"><img src="https://storage.googleapis.com/aodour_v1/website/track_icon.png" alt="img here"></a></div><div class="navigation-menu center"><nav><ul><li><a href="/"> Home</a></li><li><a href="/">Brands</a><div class="mega-menu"><div class="mega-content"><div class="list-column side-list"><h6 class="mb14">Brand A-Z</h6><h6>New Brands</h6><ul class="list"><li><a href="/brand/loreal">L'Oréal</a></li><li><a href="/brand/kerastase">Kerastase</a></li><li><a href="/brand/hemani">WB By Hemani</a></li><li><a href="/brand/beauty_blender">Beauty Blender</a></li><li><a href="/brand/loreal-professional">L'ORÉAL Professional</a></li></ul><h6>Featured Brands</h6><ul class="list"><li><a href="/brand/the-ordinary">The Ordinary</a></li><li><a href="/brand/some-by-mi">Some By Mi</a></li><li><a href="/brand/soap-glory">Soap&amp;Glory</a></li><li><a href="/brand/milani">Milani</a></li><li><a href="/brand/mario-badescu">Mario Badescu</a></li></ul></div><div class="tab-mega"><div class="search-filter"><div class="row"><div class="col-md-12"><div class="search_items"><ul class="list"><li><a href="/brand/a-h-c">A.H.C</a></li><li><a href="/brand/adidas">Adidas</a></li><li><a href="/brand/anastasia">Anastasia</a></li><li><a href="/brand/art-deco">Art Deco</a></li><li><a href="/brand/astra-make-up">Astra Make-Up</a></li><li><a href="/brand/aura-crafts">Aura Crafts</a></li><li><a href="/brand/auragano">Auragano</a></li><li><a href="/brand/aussie">Aussie</a></li><li><a href="/brand/aztec-secret">Aztec Secret</a></li><li><a href="/brand/barry-m">Barry M</a></li><li><a href="/brand/beauty-buffet">Beauty Buffet</a></li><li><a href="/brand/beauty-uk">Beauty Uk</a></li><li><a href="/brand/benefit">Benefit</a></li><li><a href="/brand/bh-cosmetics">BH Cosmetics</a></li><li><a href="/brand/biore">Biore</a></li><li><a href="/brand/bnatural">Bnatural</a></li><li><a href="/brand/bnatural-beauty">Bnatural Beauty</a></li><li><a href="/brand/bobbi-brown">Bobbi Brown</a></li><li><a href="/brand/boots">Boots</a></li><li><a href="/brand/botanical-wonders">Botanical Wonders</a></li><li><a href="/brand/bourjois">Bourjois</a></li><li><a href="/brand/burts-bees">Burt's Bees</a></li><li><a href="/brand/cailyn">Cailyn</a></li><li><a href="/brand/chanel">Chanel</a></li><li><a href="/brand/christian-dior">Christian Dior</a></li><li><a href="/brand/city-color">City Color</a></li><li><a href="/brand/clarins">Clarins</a></li><li><a href="/brand/clinique">Clinique</a></li><li><a href="/brand/co-natural">Co Natural</a></li><li><a href="/brand/color-studio-professional">Color Studio Pakistan</a></li><li><a href="/brand/colourpop">ColourPop</a></li><li><a href="/brand/comfort-zone">Comfort Zone</a></li><li><a href="/brand/cosrx">Cosrx</a></li><li><a href="/brand/coty-airspun">Coty Airspun</a></li><li><a href="/brand/dari-mooch">Dari Mooch</a></li><li><a href="/brand/dermalogica">Dermalogica</a></li><li><a href="/brand/dermatix">Dermatix</a></li><li><a href="/brand/double-dare">Double Dare</a></li><li><a href="/brand/drg">Dr.G</a></li><li><a href="/brand/dr-jart">Dr.Jart+</a></li><li><a href="/brand/drs">DRS</a></li><li><a href="/brand/elf-cosmetics">ELF</a></li><li><a href="/brand/essence">Essence</a></li><li><a href="/brand/estee-lauder">Estee Lauder</a></li><li><a href="/brand/etude-house">Etude House</a></li><li><a href="/brand/eveline">Eveline</a></li><li><a href="/brand/fara">FA'RA</a></li><li><a href="/brand/femfresh">Femfresh</a></li><li><a href="/brand/first-aid-beauty">First Aid Beauty</a></li><li><a href="/brand/focallure">Focallure</a></li><li><a href="/brand/framesi">Framesi</a></li><li><a href="/brand/gabrini">Gabrini</a></li><li><a href="/brand/garnier">Garnier</a></li><li><a href="/brand/glam-glow">Glam Glow</a></li><li><a href="/brand/glow-recipe">Glow Recipe</a></li><li><a href="/brand/go-natural">Go Natural</a></li><li><a href="/brand/gosh">Gosh</a></li><li><a href="/brand/hair-energy">Hair Energy</a></li><li><a href="/brand/huda-beauty">Huda Beauty</a></li><li><a href="/brand/imdk">IMDK</a></li><li><a href="/brand/innisfree">Innisfree</a></li><li><a href="/brand/it-s-skin">ITS SKIN</a></li><li><a href="/brand/janssen">Janssen</a></li><li><a href="/brand/jayjun">Jayjun</a></li><li><a href="/brand/john-frieda">John Frieda</a></li><li><a href="/brand/jovan">Jovan</a></li><li><a href="/brand/aodour">JR</a></li><li><a href="/brand/just-for-men">Just For Men</a></li><li><a href="/brand/kerastase">Kerastase</a></li><li><a href="/brand/kiehls">Kiehls</a></li><li><a href="/brand/kinimo-cosmetics">Kinimo Cosmetics</a></li><li><a href="/brand/knc-beauty">KNC BEAUTY</a></li><li><a href="/brand/kryolan">Kryolan</a></li><li><a href="/brand/l-a-girl">L.A Girl</a></li><li><a href="/brand/loreal">L'Oréal</a></li><li><a href="/brand/loreal-professional">L'ORÉAL Professional</a></li><li><a href="/brand/lakme">Lakme</a></li><li><a href="/brand/lancome">Lancome</a></li><li><a href="/brand/laneige">Laneige</a></li><li><a href="/brand/luscious">Luscious</a></li><li><a href="/brand/mac">MAC</a></li><li><a href="/brand/makeup-forever">Makeup Forever</a></li><li><a href="/brand/mario-badescu">Mario Badescu</a></li><li><a href="/brand/max-factor">Max Factor</a></li><li><a href="/brand/maybelline">Maybelline</a></li><li><a href="/brand/mediheal">Mediheal</a></li><li><a href="/brand/milani">Milani</a></li><li><a href="/brand/miniso">Miniso</a></li><li><a href="/brand/mise-en-scene">Misen En Scene</a></li><li><a href="/brand/missha">Missha</a></li><li><a href="/brand/misslyn">Misslyn</a></li><li><a href="/brand/mistine">Mistine</a></li><li><a href="/brand/morphe">Morphe</a></li><li><a href="/brand/mua">MUA</a></li><li><a href="/brand/nars">NARS</a></li><li><a href="/brand/natural-fervor-vitamin">Natural Fervor Vitamin</a></li><li><a href="/brand/neutrogena">Neutrogena</a></li><li><a href="/brand/nexton">Nexton</a></li><li><a href="/brand/nisim">Nisim</a></li><li><a href="/brand/nutrifactor">NutriFactor</a></li><li><a href="/brand/nyx">NYX</a></li><li><a href="/brand/ogx">OGX</a></li><li><a href="/brand/origins">Origins</a></li><li><a href="/brand/ostruce">Ostruce</a></li><li><a href="/brand/papa-recipe">Papa Recipe</a></li><li><a href="/brand/paul-mitchell">Paul Mitchell</a></li><li><a href="/brand/phb-ethical-beauty">PHB Ethical Beauty</a></li><li><a href="/brand/pixi">Pixi</a></li><li><a href="/brand/redken">Redken</a></li><li><a href="/brand/ren">REN</a></li><li><a href="/brand/rimmel-london">Rimmel London</a></li><li><a href="/brand/rohto">Rohto</a></li><li><a href="/brand/sampure">Sampure</a></li><li><a href="/brand/sand-sky">Sand &amp; Sky</a></li><li><a href="/brand/sephora">SEPHORA</a></li><li><a href="/brand/shangpree">Shangpree</a></li><li><a href="/brand/shine-k">Shine K</a></li><li><a href="/brand/shiseido">Shiseido</a></li><li><a href="/brand/simple-r">Simple</a></li><li><a href="/brand/skin-nature">Skin Nature</a></li><li><a href="/brand/smash-box">Smash Box</a></li><li><a href="/brand/soap-glory">Soap&amp;Glory</a></li><li><a href="/brand/some-by-mi">Some By Mi</a></li><li><a href="/brand/spa-in-a-bottle">SPA In A Bottle</a></li><li><a href="/brand/st-london">St. London</a></li><li><a href="/brand/st-ives">St.Ives</a></li><li><a href="/brand/stageline">Stageline</a></li><li><a href="/brand/stila">Stila</a></li><li><a href="/brand/superdrug">Superdrug</a></li><li><a href="/brand/t-zone">T Zone</a></li><li><a href="/brand/tarte">Tarte</a></li><li><a href="/brand/thayers">Thayers</a></li><li><a href="/brand/the-body-shop">The Body Shop</a></li><li><a href="/brand/the-face-shop">The Face Shop</a></li><li><a href="/brand/the-inkey-list">The Inkey List</a></li><li><a href="/brand/the-ordinary">The Ordinary</a></li><li><a href="/brand/thursday-plantation">Thursday Plantation</a></li><li><a href="/brand/tiam">TIAM</a></li><li><a href="/brand/trilogy">Trilogy</a></li><li><a href="/brand/true">True</a></li><li><a href="/brand/truly-komal">Truly Komal</a></li><li><a href="/brand/urban-decay">Urban Decay</a></li><li><a href="/brand/versus">Versus</a></li><li><a href="/brand/vichy">Vichy</a></li><li><a href="/brand/vince">Vince</a></li><li><a href="/brand/hemani">WB By Hemani</a></li><li><a href="/brand/wet-wild">Wet &amp; Wild</a></li><li><a href="/brand/wet-brush">Wet Brush</a></li><li><a href="/brand/white">White</a></li><li><a href="/brand/xhekpon">Xhekpon</a></li><li><a href="/brand/zara">Zara</a></li></ul></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></li><li><a href="/">Products</a><div class="mega-menu"><div class="mega-content"><ul class="nav nav-list"><li class="active"><a href="/shop/skin-care"> Skin Care </a></li><li class=""><a href="/shop/make-up"> Make Up </a></li><li class=""><a href="/shop/bath-body"> Bath &amp; Body </a></li><li class=""><a href="/shop/hair"> Hair </a></li><li class=""><a href="/shop/health"> Health </a></li><li class=""><a href="/shop/fragrance"> Fragrance </a></li><li class=""><a href="/shop/baby-mother-care"> Baby &amp; Mother Care </a></li><li class=""><a href="/shop/personal-care"> Personal Care </a></li><li class=""><a href="/shop/textile"> Textile </a></li><li class=""><a href="/shop/life-department"> Home &amp; Life Style </a></li><li class=""><a href="/shop/bags-accessories"> Watch, Bags &amp; Fashion </a></li><li class=""><a href="/shop/electronics-electrical-appliances"> Electronics &amp; Appliances </a></li></ul><div class="tab-mega"><div class="row"><div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><div class="row"><div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12"><div class="list-column"><a href="/subcategory/value-gift-sets-3"><h6>Value &amp; Gift Set</h6></a><ul class="list"><li><a href="/shop/skin-care/skin-care-kit-1">Skin Care Set</a></li></ul></div><div class="list-column"><a href="/subcategory/moisturizers"><h6>Moisturizers</h6></a><ul class="list"><li><a href="/shop/skin-care/moisturizer-1">Moisturizer</a></li><li><a href="/shop/skin-care/night-creams">Night Cream</a></li><li><a href="/shop/skin-care/face-oils">Face Oil</a></li><li><a href="/shop/skin-care/mists-essences">Mist &amp; Essence</a></li></ul></div><div class="list-column"><a href="/subcategory/sun-care"><h6>Sun Care</h6></a><ul class="list"><li><a href="/shop/skin-care/face-sunscreen">Face Sunscreen</a></li></ul></div></div><div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12"><div class="list-column"><a href="/subcategory/face-treatments"><h6>Face Treatment</h6></a><ul class="list"><li><a href="/shop/skin-care/serums-essence">Face Serum</a></li><li><a href="/shop/skin-care/blemish-acne-treatments">Blemish &amp; Acne Treatment</a></li><li><a href="/shop/skin-care/anti-aging-creams">Anti Aging Cream</a></li><li><a href="/shop/skin-care/lightning-brightening">Lightning &amp; Brightening</a></li></ul></div><div class="list-column"><a href="/subcategory/high-tech-tools"><h6>High Tech Tool</h6></a><ul class="list"><li><a href="/shop/skin-care/cleansing">Facial Cleansing</a></li><li><a href="/shop/skin-care/hair-removal">Hair Removal</a></li><li><a href="/shop/skin-care/massagers">Facial Massager</a></li><li><a href="/shop/skin-care/facial-rollers">Facial Roller</a></li><li><a href="/shop/skin-care/facial-steamer">Facial Steamer</a></li></ul></div><div class="list-column"><a href="/subcategory/masks"><h6>Mask</h6></a><ul class="list"><li><a href="/shop/skin-care/face-masks">Face Mask</a></li><li><a href="/shop/skin-care/sheet-masks">Sheet Mask</a></li><li><a href="/shop/skin-care/foot-masks">Foot Mask</a></li><li><a href="/shop/skin-care/hand-masks">Hand Mask</a></li><li><a href="/shop/skin-care/nose-strips">Nose Strip</a></li></ul></div></div><div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12"><div class="list-column"><a href="/subcategory/eye-care"><h6>Eye Care</h6></a><ul class="list"><li><a href="/shop/skin-care/eye-masks">Eye Mask</a></li><li><a href="/shop/skin-care/eye-creams-treatments">Eye Cream &amp; Treatment</a></li><li><a href="/shop/skin-care/eye-serums">Eye Serum</a></li></ul></div><div class="list-column"><a href="/subcategory/cleanser"><h6>Cleansers</h6></a><ul class="list"><li><a href="/shop/skin-care/scrub-4">Exfoliator</a></li><li><a href="/shop/skin-care/makeup-removers">Makeup Remover</a></li><li><a href="/shop/skin-care/cleansers">Face Wash &amp; Cleanser</a></li><li><a href="/shop/skin-care/cleansing-wipes">Cleansing Wipe</a></li><li><a href="/shop/skin-care/toners">Toner</a></li></ul></div><div class="list-column"><a href="/subcategory/lip-treatment"><h6>Lip Treatment</h6></a><ul class="list"><li><a href="/shop/skin-care/lip-care">Lip Balm &amp; Treatment</a></li></ul></div></div></div></div><div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 "><div class="list-column mb20"><figure><a href="https://www.aodour.pk/brand/neutrogena" target="_blank"><img src="/assets/images/categorymenu.jpg" alt="neutrogena"></a></figure></div><div class="list-column mb20"><figure><a href="https://www.aodour.pk/brand/etude-house" target="_blank"><img src="/assets/images/categorymenu2.jpg" alt="etude house"></a></figure></div></div></div></div></div></div></li><li><a href="/Shop/new_arrival">New Arrivals</a></li><li><a href="/brand/loreal/home">Professional haircare</a></li><li><a href="/mega-sale">Summer End Sale</a></li></ul></nav></div><div class="pull-right"><div class="right-btns"><ul class="shop_cart meta"><li><button type="button" class="search-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#search"><i class="icon-search"></i></button></li><li class=""><small class="user_account"><i class="icon-user" aria-hidden="true"></i></small><div class="perfile_dropdown "><ul class="dropmenu"><li><a href="/profile"><i class="icon-user1"></i>My Profile</a></li><li><a href="/profile/myorders"><i class="fa fa-archive" aria-hidden="true"></i>My Orders</a></li><li><a href="/track-complaint"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle" aria-hidden="true"></i>Track Complaint</a></li><li><a href="/profile/mywishlist"><i class="icon-null-2"></i>My Wishlist</a></li><li><a href="/profile/myaddress"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>My Addresses</a></li><li><a href="/"><i class="icon-null-9"></i>Log Out</a></li></ul></div></li><li class=""><span class="carticon"><img src="/assets/images/cart.svg" alt="cart"><sup class="qty-show">0</sup></span><div class="empty_box dropdowncart"><h6 class="">your basket is empty.</h6></div></li></ul></div></div></div></div></div></header><div style="min-height: 100vh;"><div class="hide"><div class="loader_container"><img src="/static/media/160.ca5958b8.gif" alt="loader"></div></div><div class="inner-banner"><div class="container-fluid"><ul class="breadcrumbs"><li><a href="/">Home</a></li><li><a href="/">Brands</a></li><li>WB By Hemani</li></ul></div></div><div class="menu_button"><span class="filter_btn"><div class="listbutton_mobile"><span>Explore Brands</span></div> <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></span></div><div class="content"><div class="rtl-content"><div class="container-fluid"><div class="row"><div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12"><div class="side_widgets widget_filter"><div class="widget_links border-b"><h5 class="widget_title">Category <span class="icon-minus" aria-hidden="true"></span></h5><div class="collapse-css-transition" style="overflow: hidden;"><div class="accordian-div"><ul class=""><li class=""><a href="/brand/hemani?category=skin-care">Skin Care (52) <span></span></a><ul class="listing_child"><li class=""><a href="/brand/hemani?category=skin-care&amp;subcategory=face-treatments">Face Treatment (27) <span></span></a><ul class="listing_child"><li class=""><a href="/brand/hemani?category=skin-care&amp;subcategory=face-treatments&amp;subsubcategory=serums-essence">Face Serum (14) <span></span></a></li><li class=""><a href="/brand/hemani?category=skin-care&amp;subcategory=face-treatments&amp;subsubcategory=blemish-acne-treatments">Blemish &amp; Acne Treatment (6) <span></span></a></li><li class=""><a href="/brand/hemani?category=skin-care&amp;subcategory=face-treatments&amp;subsubcategory=lightning-brightening">Lightning &amp; Brightening (4) <span></span></a></li><li class=""><a href="/brand/hemani?category=skin-care&amp;subcategory=face-treatments&amp;subsubcategory=anti-aging-creams">Anti Aging Cream (3) <span></span></a></li></ul></li><li class=""><a href="/brand/hemani?category=skin-care&amp;subcategory=cleanser">Cleansers (13) <span></span></a><ul class="listing_child"><li class=""><a href="/brand/hemani?category=skin-care&amp;subcategory=cleanser&amp;subsubcategory=cleansers">Face Wash &amp; Cleanser (8) <span></span></a></li><li class=""><a href="/brand/hemani?category=skin-care&amp;subcategory=cleanser&amp;subsubcategory=scrub-4">Exfoliator (3) <span></span></a></li><li class=""><a href="/brand/hemani?category=skin-care&amp;subcategory=cleanser&amp;subsubcategory=makeup-removers">Makeup Remover (2) <span></span></a></li></ul></li><li class=""><a href="/brand/hemani?category=skin-care&amp;subcategory=moisturizers">Moisturizers (10) <span></span></a><ul class="listing_child"><li class=""><a href="/brand/hemani?category=skin-care&amp;subcategory=moisturizers&amp;subsubcategory=moisturizer-1">Moisturizer (7) <span></span></a></li><li class=""><a href="/brand/hemani?category=skin-care&amp;subcategory=moisturizers&amp;subsubcategory=night-creams">Night Cream (3) <span></span></a></li></ul></li><li class=""><a href="/brand/hemani?category=skin-care&amp;subcategory=lip-treatment">Lip Treatment (1) <span></span></a><ul class="listing_child"><li class=""><a href="/brand/hemani?category=skin-care&amp;subcategory=lip-treatment&amp;subsubcategory=lip-care">Lip Balm &amp; Treatment (1) <span></span></a></li></ul></li><li class=""><a href="/brand/hemani?category=skin-care&amp;subcategory=masks">Mask (1) <span></span></a><ul class="listing_child"><li class=""><a href="/brand/hemani?category=skin-care&amp;subcategory=masks&amp;subsubcategory=face-masks">Face Mask (1) <span></span></a></li></ul></li></ul></li><li class=""><a href="/brand/hemani?category=make-up">Make Up (22) <span></span></a><ul class="listing_child"><li class=""><a href="/brand/hemani?category=make-up&amp;subcategory=lips">Lips (10) <span></span></a><ul class="listing_child"><li class=""><a href="/brand/hemani?category=make-up&amp;subcategory=lips&amp;subsubcategory=liquid-lipstick">Liquid Lipstick (5) <span></span></a></li><li class=""><a href="/brand/hemani?category=make-up&amp;subcategory=lips&amp;subsubcategory=lip-sticks">Lip Stick (3) <span></span></a></li><li class=""><a href="/brand/hemani?category=make-up&amp;subcategory=lips&amp;subsubcategory=lip-gloss">Lip Gloss (1) <span></span></a></li><li class=""><a href="/brand/hemani?category=make-up&amp;subcategory=lips&amp;subsubcategory=lip-tint-lip-stain">Lip Tint &amp; Lip Stain (1) <span></span></a></li></ul></li><li class=""><a href="/brand/hemani?category=make-up&amp;subcategory=face">Face (9) <span></span></a><ul class="listing_child"><li class=""><a href="/brand/hemani?category=make-up&amp;subcategory=face&amp;subsubcategory=finishing-powders-setting-sprays">Finishing Powder &amp; Setting Spray (2) <span></span></a></li><li class=""><a href="/brand/hemani?category=make-up&amp;subcategory=face&amp;subsubcategory=bronzers-highlighters">Bronzer &amp; Highlighter (1) <span></span></a></li><li class=""><a href="/brand/hemani?category=make-up&amp;subcategory=face&amp;subsubcategory=liquid-highlighter">Liquid Highlighter (1) <span></span></a></li><li class=""><a href="/brand/hemani?category=make-up&amp;subcategory=face&amp;subsubcategory=foundations">Foundation (1) <span></span></a></li><li class=""><a href="/brand/hemani?category=make-up&amp;subcategory=face&amp;subsubcategory=concealers">Concealer (1) <span></span></a></li><li class=""><a href="/brand/hemani?category=make-up&amp;subcategory=face&amp;subsubcategory=compacts">Compact (1) <span></span></a></li><li class=""><a href="/brand/hemani?category=make-up&amp;subcategory=face&amp;subsubcategory=contouring">Contouring (1) <span></span></a></li><li class=""><a href="/brand/hemani?category=make-up&amp;subcategory=face&amp;subsubcategory=blush-ons">Blush-On (1) <span></span></a></li></ul></li><li class=""><a href="/brand/hemani?category=make-up&amp;subcategory=nails">Nails (1) <span></span></a><ul class="listing_child"><li class=""><a href="/brand/hemani?category=make-up&amp;subcategory=nails&amp;subsubcategory=nail-accessories">Nail Accessories (1) <span></span></a></li></ul></li><li class=""><a href="/brand/hemani?category=make-up&amp;subcategory=brushes-applicators">Brush &amp; Applicator (1) <span></span></a><ul class="listing_child"><li class=""><a href="/brand/hemani?category=make-up&amp;subcategory=brushes-applicators&amp;subsubcategory=brush-sets">Brush Set (1) <span></span></a></li></ul></li><li class=""><a href="/brand/hemani?category=make-up&amp;subcategory=eyes">Eyes (1) <span></span></a><ul class="listing_child"><li class=""><a href="/brand/hemani?category=make-up&amp;subcategory=eyes&amp;subsubcategory=eye-palettes">Eye Palette (1) <span></span></a></li></ul></li></ul></li><li class=""><a href="/brand/hemani?category=hair">Hair (11) <span></span></a><ul class="listing_child"><li class=""><a href="/brand/hemani?category=hair&amp;subcategory=hair-care">Shampoo &amp; Conditioner (5) <span></span></a><ul class="listing_child"><li class=""><a href="/brand/hemani?category=hair&amp;subcategory=hair-care&amp;subsubcategory=shampoo">Shampoo (4) <span></span></a></li><li class=""><a href="/brand/hemani?category=hair&amp;subcategory=hair-care&amp;subsubcategory=conditioner">Conditioner (1) <span></span></a></li></ul></li><li class=""><a href="/brand/hemani?category=hair&amp;subcategory=hair-styling">Hair Styling &amp; Treatment (5) <span></span></a><ul class="listing_child"><li class=""><a href="/brand/hemani?category=hair&amp;subcategory=hair-styling&amp;subsubcategory=hair-oils-1">Hair Oil (3) <span></span></a></li><li class=""><a href="/brand/hemani?category=hair&amp;subcategory=hair-styling&amp;subsubcategory=hair-mask">Hair Mask (1) <span></span></a></li><li class=""><a href="/brand/hemani?category=hair&amp;subcategory=hair-styling&amp;subsubcategory=hair-spray">Hair Spray (1) <span></span></a></li></ul></li><li class=""><a href="/brand/hemani?category=hair&amp;subcategory=hair-tools">Hair Tool (1) <span></span></a><ul class="listing_child"><li class=""><a href="/brand/hemani?category=hair&amp;subcategory=hair-tools&amp;subsubcategory=hair-brushes-combs">Hair Brush &amp; Comb (1) <span></span></a></li></ul></li></ul></li><li class=""><a href="/brand/hemani?category=bath-body">Bath &amp; Body (11) <span></span></a><ul class="listing_child"><li class=""><a href="/brand/hemani?category=bath-body&amp;subcategory=bath-shower">Bath &amp; Shower (5) <span></span></a><ul class="listing_child"><li class=""><a href="/brand/hemani?category=bath-body&amp;subcategory=bath-shower&amp;subsubcategory=hand-wash-soap">Hand Wash &amp; Soap (3) <span></span></a></li><li class=""><a href="/brand/hemani?category=bath-body&amp;subcategory=bath-shower&amp;subsubcategory=body-wash">Body Wash (1) <span></span></a></li><li class=""><a href="/brand/hemani?category=bath-body&amp;subcategory=bath-shower&amp;subsubcategory=accessories-1">Accessories (1) <span></span></a></li></ul></li><li class=""><a href="/brand/hemani?category=bath-body&amp;subcategory=body-moisturizer">Body Moisturizer (4) <span></span></a><ul class="listing_child"><li class=""><a href="/brand/hemani?category=bath-body&amp;subcategory=body-moisturizer&amp;subsubcategory=hand-cream-foot-cream">Hand Cream &amp; Foot Cream (2) <span></span></a></li><li class=""><a href="/brand/hemani?category=bath-body&amp;subcategory=body-moisturizer&amp;subsubcategory=body-cream">Body Cream (2) <span></span></a></li></ul></li><li class=""><a href="/brand/hemani?category=bath-body&amp;subcategory=body-care">Body Care (2) <span></span></a><ul class="listing_child"><li class=""><a href="/brand/hemani?category=bath-body&amp;subcategory=body-care&amp;subsubcategory=body-oil">Body Oil (1) <span></span></a></li><li class=""><a href="/brand/hemani?category=bath-body&amp;subcategory=body-care&amp;subsubcategory=slimming-cream">Slimming Cream (1) <span></span></a></li></ul></li></ul></li><li class=""><a href="/brand/hemani?category=baby-mother-care">Baby &amp; Mother Care (4) <span></span></a><ul class="listing_child"><li class=""><a href="/brand/hemani?category=baby-mother-care&amp;subcategory=baby-care">Baby Care (4) <span></span></a><ul class="listing_child"><li class=""><a href="/brand/hemani?category=baby-mother-care&amp;subcategory=baby-care&amp;subsubcategory=cream-lotions-oils">Cream, Lotions &amp; Oil (3) <span></span></a></li><li class=""><a href="/brand/hemani?category=baby-mother-care&amp;subcategory=baby-care&amp;subsubcategory=value-gifts-6">Value &amp; Gift (1) <span></span></a></li></ul></li></ul></li><li class=""><a href="/brand/hemani?category=health">Health (3) <span></span></a><ul class="listing_child"><li class=""><a href="/brand/hemani?category=health&amp;subcategory=supplements-and-vitamins">Supplement and Vitamin (3) <span></span></a>
  </body></html>
  ```