# Download a file by clicking without url using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm trying to download files from a website using python. I want it to be automaticaly downloaded but this button don't have an url or xpath. I tried this code but I didn't found a good result :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
download_dir = 'C:/Users/ASUS/Documents/data'

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/chrome/chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("http://www.ins.tn/statistiques/90#")
button = driver.find_element_by_class_name('btnexport')
button.click()
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but the button cannot magically download something, mustn't there be an URL somewhere in the website's front-end code?

Comment: Take a look on [Is there any way to download csv file from “website button click” using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55918415/10824407).

Comment: @Mandera this is what i found about the button : <a id="btnExporttoExcel-0" class="btnexport  " href="#"><i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>

Comment: @Mandera Actually it's a `<a>` tag. So it does downloads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To click on the icon to download the excel you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.execute("get", {'url': 'http://www.ins.tn/statistiques/90#'})
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.export a.btnexport[id^='btnExporttoExcel']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.execute("get", {'url': 'http://www.ins.tn/statistiques/90#'})
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='export']//a[@class='btnexport  ' and starts-with(@id, 'btnExporttoExcel')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: download]

Comment: That's perfectly work , thank you so much